# How to add child page to author.php

Tags: author, author-template

I would like to know if it's possible to add child page to author.php ? like this : author/user_id/about... /author/user_id/activity...

If it's possible, could you show me a sample of code ?

Thank you

Comment: `author.php` is just a template, it doesn't have tabs unless you implement them from scratch what did you intend to put on this tab? Your question can be simplified to _how do I put tabs on a page_

Comment: sorry, i meant if it's possible to add child page to author.php ? like this : author/user_id/about... /author/user_id/activity... like buddypress

Comment: Can you edit your question to reflect that? What you're asking is completely different, most people won't read the comments to find that out. There's an edit link at the bottom of the question below the tags